# What's the equivalent of Google Cloud Logging for Azure App Services APIs?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, google-cloud-logging, azure-appservice

Here is what I am familiar with in GCP. I was able to deploy a spring boot REST API to GAE (Google App Engine) and see all the startup + running logging in Cloud Logging.

It looks really nice and lints the logging cleanly:

[image]

When I try to accomplish the same thing with Azure, and deploy the same Spring Boot REST API to Azure "App Service", I have no idea whether something similar exists.

In Deployment Center, I have it configured to push up my code via Github Actions via the following default yaml script:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Java version
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '11'

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v1
      with:
        app-name: '**********'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_12ee0e892d9c498898a01f1268a3dbd4 }}
        package: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'
```

It might be relevant to note that initially this document said it was to deploy a "WAR" app, but I just changed the file it was looking from, from `.war` to `.jar`. I didn't really see any options in App Service to configure it to expect a SBA (spring boot application) but Google didn't need me to tell it how to run the app so why would Azure?

Anyway, the main reason I'm trying to hunt down these logs are because I'm unable to access the api endpoint I have exposed that works on localhost. I get a message saying `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` and this is the Application Logging I get (Monitoring -> Log Stream) upon trying (I manually rendered the raw html output):

[image]

Does Azure have any kind of cloud logging that can clue me into why my vanilla spring app just 404's in prod?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your Java Web App in App Service, there are few options:

1. "Java SE" (Windows/Linux): This option is to run embedded Web server stacks like SpringBoot, you jar should be named app.jar
2. "Tomcat" (Windows/Linux): This option is to run Web archives and we recommend to use an app.war file.

Here is our quickstart for Java Web Apps on Azure App Service in Windows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-java

Here is our quickstart for Java Web Apps on Azure App Service in Linux:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-java

For enabling diagnostic logs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Additionally, we are working on integration with Azure Monitor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor-preview

If this is still not working for you, no worries. Feel free to open a support case with Azure and we will assist. This is the preferred option as we will need the site name to investigate.

To create an Azure support request:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: i think very likely the issue stemmed from me selecting `Tomcat 9.0` instead of `Java SE` because there was no information accompanying the dropdown menu, so I assumed i needed some kind of tomcat server

Comment: can I ask if there are any downsides to deploying a spring boot app which is basically just a rest api, as a **Web App** app service vs an **API App** app service? It's just that I could only find direct plugin support for `<artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>` and nothing for "apiapp"

Comment: The short answer is to use Azure App Service. Azure API Apps is an outdated term, the service has been consolidated into App Service. If you go to the landing page for API Apps, all the docs links go to Azure App Service.

Comment: right, but API Apps still exist as a separate entity from Web apps. They have different icons in Azure App Service and are created differently

Answer (score 0):

The Azure equivalent to Google Cloud Logging is **Azure Monitor Log**, which combine Log Analytics, and Application Insights.

Learn how to query logs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview)

Answer (score 0):

Also on Azure you can use Log stream on Azure portal to view live logs 
https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip30.html